# Mediator 9: Sending a user defined variable to DB

Tags: sql, ms-access, odbc

I'm using Matchware Mediator 9 (a truly awful program) and I'm attempting to create a user registration page. I've linked to an MS Access database, and I am able to input data using SQL's Insert Into function. However, I can't submit user defined data because I'm not sure how to link the user defined variable in the SQL query.

```
"INSERT INTO Test (FirstName)
VALUES (varFirstName)"
```

This is what I have, but it's throwing the following error.

```
Database SQL error: [Microsoft] [ODBC Text Driver] Too few parameters. Expected:1
```

If I change **(varFirstName)** to **('Test')** then it will input the word *Test* to the correct column in access. Any idea how to send the user defined variable from mediator using the SQL statement, I've tried @varFirstName , &varFirstName, $varFirstName and '"varFirstName"' - however they all give me this error instead

```
Database SQL error: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Syntax error in query expression '$varFirstName'
```

Answer (score 0):

Concatenate the variable:

```
SQL = "INSERT INTO Test (FirstName) VALUES ('" & varFirstName & "')"
```